# d3 Hexagonal Binning domain and range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a hexagonal binning graph based on this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4248145

I've already figured out how to set the domain of each axis. But I'm having troubles setting the points, and I think this is because of the range.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width  = 800 - margin.left - margin.right, // 740px
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom; // 450px

var points = [[1000,30],[5000,40],[8000,50]]

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10000]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([18, 65]).range([height, 0]);
```

Using these points, the graph comes out blank.

But if I try these points:

```
var points = [[100,30],[200,40],[300,50]]
```

They appear on the graph but not even close to where they should be. `[100,30]`, for example, it appears what should be something like `[1400,62]`.

I already read [this post about scales on d3](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales). But I haven't figured out how to display the points correctly.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/P6KWZ/

Comment: You need to set the domain of your scales dynamically based on the values you have.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck http://jsfiddle.net/P6KWZ/1/

Comment: So in this case you need to use identity scales because the output of your hexbin (and therefore input to your scale) is the pixel range of the chart: http://jsfiddle.net/P6KWZ/2/

Comment: If I do this the scale is shown in pixels in both axis. And if I have a point `[5000,30]`, I need to build a SVG 5000px wide. Only if the axis from your example could be, let's say, converted, it would do the job.

Comment: You can also determine the domains based on the projected points and then translate the hexagons with translated values: http://jsfiddle.net/P6KWZ/3/

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks. Make it an answer and I mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things in your jsfiddle. First, you're not actually using the scales you've created to position the hexagons. Second, you're computing the domains based on the original values and the drawing the values computed by the hexbin.

So first compute the domains based on the binned values:

```
var projectedPoints = hexbin(points);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(projectedPoints, function(d) { return d.x; }))
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(projectedPoints, function(d) { return d.y; }))
    .range([height, 0]);
```

And then translate the hexagons using the scales:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; })
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P6KWZ/3/).